# How to use nginx if's param $1 in rewrite statement

Tags: nginx

I have this working code in nginx config:

```
if ($http_host ~* ^www\.(.+)$) {
    set $host2 $1;
    rewrite  (.*)  http://$host2$1;
}
```

I think that string `set $host2 $1;` may be omitted and $1 used in rewrite statement without defining some variables. But rewrite has own $1..$9 params.

How I may use $1 form if in the rewrite statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the regex dollar forms only apply to the most recent regular expression.  So you cannot combine the `$1` of the `if` with the `$1` of the `rewrite` without using `set`.  However, there are simpler solutions for your scenario.

Firstly, if you know the host name (for example `example.com`), you can do the following:

```
server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}
server { server_name example.com; ... }
```

On the other hand, if you don't have a specific host name in mind, you can do the following catch-all solution:

```
server {
    server_name ~^www\.(?<domain>.+)$;
    return 301 $scheme://$domain$request_uri;
}
server { server_name _; ... }
```

You can find out more about this second form [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html).

I don't recommend catch-all solutions because it is only meaningful to have at most one catch-all server block.  If possible, use the named server solution.

Also, note that you can achieve the above redirection using the `rewrite ^ destination permanent;` form.  All these solutions avoid using the poorly regarded `if` directive.

Comment: Never thought of the general catch all solution before, always used the first method (301 redirect) with a hard coded domain name, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady :-)

Comment: In this config I have one server block with ip address in server_name. This server hosts many sites by drupal multisiting feature. This is a reason why I seek the way caonfig my server in one directive, without specifying hostname in config.
Thank you for your answer, I will try it in my server.

Comment: Is your config better than my version? (I know that if is evil, but what about perfomance of your config)

Comment: @AlexeyPavlov Your `if` should perform much like a nested `location` block. That might result in a small amount of unnecessary work in processing directives, but not enough to ever worry about.